# Save images without showing it on screen

Tags: image, matlab, loops, plot

I would like to save images to some folder without showing me on screen. I have tried following code, but it shows me on screen at each iteration.

```
 clear all
 B=xlsread('data_generations1','A1','g8:g301');
 M=length(B)/2;
 for i = 2 : M   
    X=create_matrix1(B,i);
    [U E V]=svd(X);
    figure;
    h(i-1)=plot(E(:));
    title(['windows order',num2str(i),'size']);
 end
 for i = 1 : length(h)
    saveas(h(i),sprintf('figure_%d.jpg',i))    
 end
```

I would like to save it on some folder, let say folder with name figures, so how can I do it? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [`Figure Properties` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure_props.html)

For this case we're interested in the `Visible` property: `figure('Visible','off')`

Comment: By default it will save in your current working directory. Concatenate it with your filename or incorporate it into your sprintf call if you'd like it to save somewhere else. An example of the former: saveas(h(i),[filepath sprintf('figure_%d.jpg',i)])

Comment: let say this is my  working directory,F:\all_test\MATLAB  and i want to  create new folder figures,what should be filepath?

Comment: filepath = 'F:\all_test\MATLABand\Figures\';

Comment: sorry and was  not file name :D  it is english  word :D

Comment: If the directory does not yet exist you will have to use [mkdir()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mkdir.html).

Comment: so let us  assume that  path is F:\all_test\MATLAB\figures,how it would have  final form?

Comment: If the directory exists: filepath = 'F:\all_test\MATLAB\figures\'; saveas(h(i),[filepath sprintf('figure_%d.jpg',i)])

Comment: could this code be optimized?i meant instead of loop if i use vectorization